# Can't access generic property of child class when declaring super class

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I might be currently confused, but I have the following problem.
I'm using C# but the point is more general, but I'm new to C# coming from Java.

I have a common abstract super class and multiple children.
Some children have generic properties which I can't access when I'm instantiating the a variable when declaring the common super type:

```
abstract class A
{
    public string Prop0;
}

// Here every ok when instantiated
class B: A
{
    public string Prop1;
}

// This makes trouble
class C<T> : A
{
    public T Prop2;
}
```

Now I have a method which returns some subtype of A:

```
public A DoIt()
{
    A a;
    a = new C<string>();
    a.Prop2; // <-- Can't access
}
```

(In my concrete case, the type can't be static because the child classes are serialized and have different shapes (C is a template with a property allowing anything). Still the question is general)

Why is this an issue and which solution is "correct" (except of using "object")

Comment: C extends A.  A has no way of knowing about a derived class's properties.  If you want to have access to the property, you need to declare it at the superclass level.

Comment: The behavior of C# is exactly the same as Java here - can't access properties of derived class via reference to base... Could you please clarify why you expect code to work or maybe show "equivalent" Java code that you are trying to express in C#.

Comment: I know (this is more pseudocode). but what if you have a common "shape" which is extended and adds some attributes like "radius" additionally to "x" and "y" in "shape". How do you declare that some subtype of "Shape" shall be returned/instantiated?

Comment: You can do something similar to that with c++ _templates_ but **not** .NET _generics_.  Though referencing the member variable will be done within the template

Answer (score 3):

If `a` is always going to be set to a new instance of a `C`, then simply declare it as such:

```
public A DoIt()
{
    C<string> c;
    c = new C<string>();
    var prop2 = c.Prop2;
    return c;
}
```

But if you won't know if it's a `C` or not until it gets deserialized -- which it sounds from your explanation is the case here -- then here's a way to get that property if in fact it is a `C` (or get `null` if it's not a `C`):

```
public A DoIt()
{
    A a;
    a = new C<string>();
    var prop2 = a is C<string> ? (a as C<string>).Prop2 : null;
    return a;
}
```

Basically what this second approach does is check to see if `a` is an instance of `C`, and if so, it casts `a` to `C` and then reads its `Prop2` property.

**FOLLOW-UP EXAMPLE:**

Here's code from an actual working console app that does something similar to what you've described. It's not a realistic scenario, and it may not be even close what you had in mind, but I'll post it anyway in case it gives you any ideas.

Note that this requires a reference to [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (for the `using Newtonsoft.Json;` statement below).

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var c = new C<string>() { Prop0 = "zero", Prop2 = "two" };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c);
    var prop2 = GetProp2(json);
    Console.WriteLine("prop2 from C: " + (prop2 ?? "null"));

    var b = new B() { Prop0 = "zero", Prop1 = "one" };
    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b);
    prop2 = GetProp2(json);
    Console.WriteLine("prop2 from B: " + (prop2 ?? "null"));

    Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static object GetProp2(string json)
{
    A a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<C<string>>(json);
    var prop2 = a is C<string> ? (a as C<string>).Prop2 : null;
    return prop2;
}
```

Results in the following output:

```
prop2 from C: two
prop2 from B: null
Press any key to exit...
```

Comment: As you noted, I think this is going somewhere else. I just reviewed what I did the last time something similar and I think it was in scala with an "subtype of" generic parameter. This won't work in c#. Just tried it in scala..

Answer (score 1):

Potential answer to question in comment: "How do you declare that some subtype of `Shape` shall be returned/instantiated".

If you want to specifically return `C<T>` results you can specify it as return type:

```
public C<TResult> DoIt<TResult>()
{
    C<TResult> a;
    a = new C<TResult>();
    a.Prop2; // <-- Can access
    return a;
}
```